# How to control gdb using Python subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, syntax-error

So I'm writing (or at least trying to) a program to compare the outputs of two gdb runs in python. This is what I have so far:

```
from subprocess import *
import subprocess

file = raw_input('enter program name (with a ./ if in local directory): ')

p1 = Popen(['gdb', file], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = Popen(['gdb', file], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

p1.communicate(input='break main')
p2.communicate(input='break main')

args1 = raw_input('args for running program (from file) (ie r < input.txt): ')
args2 = raw_input('args for running program (from file) (for program 2...): ')

p1.communicate(input=args1)
p2.communicate(input=args2)

while True:
    p1out = p1.communicate(input='continue')[0]
    p2out = p2.communicate(input='continue')[0]

    if p1out != p2out:
        print 'difference: '
        print 'p1: ' + p1out
        print 'p2: ' + p2out
        cont = raw_input('continue (y/n): ')
        if cont != 'y':
            break
```

Now the problem is that this doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas on where I might be going wrong?

More detail: The point of the program is to take in an executable, break at the main function, and then run through each until the output varies between the two. This is intended as a debugging tool (that I would use, even if no one else would!). Then when you find a difference it gives you the choice of whether to end the program, or to continue. In theory, this should work, but I'm just not sure what's messing up.

Comment: you should get rid of the `from subprocess import *` line and just create `subprocess.Popen` objects

Comment: (for programmatically controlling gdb from Python, there's also GDB/MI (and probably some libraries to parse it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.communicate` waits for a `Popen` object to finish execution.  Since you are trying to talk to gdb while it's running, this will just hang forever.  gdb isn't going to exit without any input.  Additionally you need to write the newlines yourself to emulate the user hitting *enter*.

what you want to do is write into and read from gdb while it is executing.  For this, use `p1.stdin.write('break main\n')` (note the `'\n'`) when sending input, and `p1.stdout.readline()` when reading output.  This applies to the break in the beginning, the args you are sending, and the continues.

On sending the arguments and beggining executing, you should also be sure to `start` gdb.

```
p1.stdin.write(f'start {args1}\n')
p2.stdin.write(f'start {args2}\n')
```

You also want to handle the case where one process terminates before another.  You can use `Popen.poll` to check if a process has completed yet, it will return `None` if it has not.  Although this may not be exactly how you want to handle it, you can change the top of your loop to something like this:

```
while True:
    if p1.poll() is not None and p2.poll() is not None:
        print 'p1 and p2 have both finished'
        break
    elif p1.poll() is not None:
        print 'p1 finished before p2'
        break
    elif p2.poll() is not None:
        print 'p2 finished before p1'
        break

    p1.stdin.write('continue\n')
    p2.stdin.write('continue\n')
    p1out = p1.stdout.readline()
    p2out = p2.stdout.readline()
```

Reading a single line will likely not be correct, and you will have to calibrate the number of lines you read in order to get the correct output.

You should either add reads to `stderr`, or send it to `/dev/null` if you don't care about it.  If you don't do either of these, the PIPE buffer can fill and cause it to hang.

Comment: but I'm putting the reads in those variables, doesn't that help to clear the buffer?

Comment: @higgs241 not for `stderr` the reads are only for `stdout`.  Since you don't use `stderr` for anything though, I'd say just throw the output out with `Popen(..., stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w')` when creating the process

Comment: you can now do `stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL` instead